# USB Type-C DRP Integrated Switch/Interface Chip

Tags: power, usb, usb-c, power-delivery

I would like to experiment with a power bank design with a single usb type-c port. The port should have dual role, source current for charging other devices as well as sink current for charging itself.

So far I've looked at various chips that can handle the usb type-c interface and set the mode via CC lines (example [TUSB320](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tusb320.pdf) series from TI) but none of these can handle the switching of VBUS with mosfets between the battery charging IC and output dc-dc converter according to the current usb mode DFP or UFP.

To achieve this function it seems I need an external controller that would monitor the USB interface chip and command the switching accordingly.

So my question is, do you know of any usb type-c interface chips that can also handle the switching without the need of an additional controller?

I don't need PD, just 5V 1.5A in and out.

Thanks!